# Writing YAML VS using Visual Designer on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am sort of new to azure devops and I had to build few builds and release pipelines.

I have done it with visual designer and it was smooth & easy, while using yaml is much more prone to mistakes.

If I work in a team that uses yaml , I do it in designer first and then copy the yaml.

Apart from saving to the repo automatically, why the pain ? why not just use the designer ?

Missing the obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now with the launch of Azure DevOps, the service really encourages using YAML. In fact, if you start a new project, those feature flags are turned on by default.

However, if you always used to do this through UI, or you're just completely new to Azure DevOps, it could be a bit confusing.

We do have a detail reference guide including a catalog of all supported YAML capabilities, and the available options-- [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema)

There are truly some benefits for using YAML,  it meant you could **use the same branching and code review practices for your build definitions** as you did for your code. And it's very useful for handling multiple build definitions.

You could also take a look at this helpful blog here:

- *[Azure Pipelines YAML - uh, what do I type?](https://damianbrady.com.au/2018/10/11/what-yaml-do-i-need-for-azure-pipelines/)*
- [*Azure Pipelines YAML #2  -  more ways to learn what YAML you need!*](https://damianbrady.com.au/2018/11/27/azure-pipelines-yaml-2-more-ways-to-learn-what-to-type/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to understand why use yaml when the designer it's simpler.The reason I used the designer bcse I was on  time constraint to deliver and learn at the same time and using yaml was very much more error prone. I will look at those links

Comment: Can you please let the user chose which one to use? It's frustrating to use YAML when you're used to the UI...and you can't do everything with yaml: "Build completion triggers are not yet supported in YAML syntax. After you create your YAML build pipeline, you can use the designer to specify a build completion trigger." But where is this damn designer?

Comment: you can choose @UNeverNo

Answer (score 2):

Because its not scalable, how do you manage hundreds of visual jobs? only by hand, yaml jobs can be mass edited, than can use templating\looping\if and so on, you can reuse them etc. I'd really wish they made yaml for releases, managing releases is a pain in Azure Devops right now, builds are easy. we've got yamls...

Comment: My main reason of the question is exactly to find the reasons why.I could not find any documentation that tells you the "dos and donts of yaml vs visual designer

Comment: its just common sense, everything is moving towards configuration is code. its never easier than visual stuff, but it is much easier to maintain\scale.

Comment: One concrete example would be that if you had hundreds of builds and need to change, say, what branches the builds are triggered from, you'd need to go through every build definition with visual editor. With yaml in version control, a simple recursive replace/insert goes a long way.

Comment: @JukkaK So why can't I use the designer as a base that generates/edits a yaml? It's just annoying to learn another dialect.

Comment: you can do that, but its not convenient to manage jobs at scale using ui

Answer (score 1):

I had same issues with new yaml only way of doing things in DevOps. User should have a choice to switch between two. For script lovers, they can always copy the generated script and automate.

I stumbled upon (after lot of reading) the setting menu hidden on the yaml code generated.
Click on the settings link and it open a details pane on the right of the page. Refer the attached image.

This is where you can provide additional details and settings value. Once saved, it reflected back in yaml script.

I hope this bridge the gap between two type of users. :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the azuredevops api for managing tasks involving bulk build and releases. Not as clean as a yaml but still a json file that you can relatively easy modify export/import etc...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).